# Using JSON file to improve caching - good idea?

Tags: django, caching, memcached

I'm a beginner to caching. I'm currently working on a small project with Django and will be implementing caching later via memcached.

I have a page with a video on it and the video has a bunch of comments. The only content on the page that is likely to change regularly is the comments and the "You are logged in as.../You are not logged in..." message.

I was thinking I could create a JSON file that serves the username and most recent comments, including it in the head with `<script src="videojson.js"></script>`. That way I could populate the HTML via Javascript instead of caching the whole page on a per-user basis.

Is this a suitable approach, or is the caching system smarter than I give it credit for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is the JavaScript going to get the json object? Are going to serve from a django view that the us calls? And in that view you will just pull out of memcached if available and DB if not?

That seems reasonable assuming your json isn't very big. If your comments change a lot and you have to spend a lot of time querying the db, building the json object and saving to memcache every time a new comment is written, it won't work well. But if you only fill the cache when your json expires, and you don't care about having the latest and greatest comments on there instantly, it should work.

One thing to point out is that if you aren't getting that much traffic now, you might be adding a level of complexity that won't give you much return on your time spent. But if you are using this to learn how to do caching then it is a good exercise.

Hope that helps